# Which is right to perform a Tukey post hoc in R?

Tags: r, post-hoc, tukey-hsd-test

I know 3 ways to perform a Tukey post-hoc test in `R` and the results are a little different.

Initially, I performed a two-way anova

```
fitmpd <- aov(mpd ~ 植物*处理)
```

I'm interested in the 处理 factor
Then, I performed a Tukey post-hoc in 3 different ways:

1. `summary(glht(fitmpd,linfct=mcp(处理="Tukey")))`
   [image: glht tukey post-hot test]
2. `TukeyHSD(fitmpd,"处理")`
   [image: tukeyHSD tukey post-hot test]
3. `HSD.test(fitmpd,"处理",console = T)`
   [image: HSD.test tukey post-hot test]

Then I found that all results are different among them.

Can anyone please tell me which one is right?

Comment: `glht` does not perform Tukey's test. The "Tukey" in the function call simply tells `glht` to compare each treatment to each other treatment, by using "Tukey contrasts". `glht` or `emmeans` are probably better than Tukey's test for routine use, as Tukey's test explicit assumptions about the distribution of the data, and `glht` or `emmeans` can be applied to a variety of model types.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few basic differences among your tests.

Tests 1. (`glht`) and 2. (`TukeyHSD`) are the same. However, the `glht` test employs a p-value adjustment method (described as the `simple-step method`), whereas `TukeyHSD` does not use p-value adjustment methods by default.

Tests 2. (`TukeyHSD`) and 3. (`HSD.test`) give the same results. Note that the `TukeyHSD` only shows that `b` statistically differs from `ck`, which is the same result given by the `HSD.test`.

Comment: `glht` and `TukeyHSD` are not the same.

Comment: The `glht` is using the Tukey test as multiple comparisons, as set by the option `linfct=mcp(处理="Tukey")`

Comment: I don't think that's correct.  That's not what "Tukey" means in that function.

Comment: Then, what it means? I'm confused with this, now

Comment: It's just telling the function to compare all levels of the variable.  You can look at the documentation for `glht` which discusses `mcp`, or look at other examples with `mcp` where it is used to define the contrasts of interest.

Comment: So "Tukey" in glht is a method to adjust p value like "bonferroni",  and TukeyHSD and HSD.test are the same traditional Tukey method of multicomparison, am I right?

Comment: @xg , in `glht` the `mcp(treat= "Tukey")` simply tells the function which things to compare.  That is, "compare all levels of *treat* against all other levels of *treat*" vs. "compare only this level vs. this other level".  `glht` makes *p*-value adjustments with a separate option, e.g. *test=adjusted("single-step")*

Comment: @xg , as far as I know, `TukeyHSD` and `HSD.test` conduct Tukey's HSD test. I assume they both use the Tukey-Kramer method that allows for somewhat unequal sample sizes, but I haven't checked. `glht`  is a different way to compare among multiple treatments. It can be be applied to different types of models (e.g. glm), and in cases of heteroscadasticity or unbalanced designs. It is therefore much more general and makes fewer assumptions than HSD. See [this paper](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/vignettes/generalsiminf.pdf).

Comment: @SalMangiafico Thank you very much, I am clear now.